# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'newsletter.model' in my Django project

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I started this Django project. Created an app called newsletter.

This is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class SignUp(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=False, null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

This is my admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
from .forms import SignUpForm
from .models import SignUp


class SignUpAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["__str__", "timestamp", "updated"]
    form = SignUpForm
    #class Meta:
     #   model = SignUp

admin.site.register(SignUp, SignUpAdmin)
```

Then i opened a forms.py:

```
from django import forms

from .model import SignUp

class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SignUp
        fields = ['email']
```

The problems is, when i tried to runserver, it gave me the error:

```
File "C:\Users\JOSHUA\Documents\trydjango18\src\newsletter\admin.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .forms import SignUpForm
  File "C:\Users\JOSHUA\Documents\trydjango18\src\newsletter\forms.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .model import SignUp
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'newsletter.model'
```

Someone please help.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your forms.py. Try:

```
from .models import SignUp
```